# Neovintageous: how to call from plugin

Tags: sublimetext4

My goal is to reload the NeoVintageous config file, that is .neovintageousrc, from inside a Sublime Text plugin.

The command should be something like

```
      view.run_command("neovintageous_reload_rc")
```

but this does not work. Any help?

Comment: The author is quite active on GitHub. I would suggest [searching the issue archive](https://github.com/NeoVintageous/NeoVintageous/issues) and then filing an issue there if you can't find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the rc file using the Command Palette command

```
NeoVintageous: Open RC File
```

and reload it using

```
NeoVintageous: Reload RC File
```

Note that after editing you need to manually reload it or restart Sublime for changes to take effect.

If you want to procedurally reload it the command is `neovintageous` with the argument `action=reload_rc_file`.

For example in a commands file:

```
{
    "caption": "NeoVintageous: Reload RC File",
    "command": "neovintageous",
    "args": { "action": "reload_rc_file" }
},
```

Or directly in python:

```
view.window().run_command("neovintageous", {"action": "reload_rc_file"})
```

**Note that you need to run the command on the window object.**

*In an older version of nv the command you used may have worked.*

See [The Neovintageous vimrc file](https://blog.gerardroche.com/2022/11/21/vimrc-and-neovintageousrc/) and `:help nv` for more documentation.